# SonarQube is not saving settings

Tags: sonarqube

Using SQ 6.2 I observe a strange behaviour: Whe I modify and save no matter which setting in the administration UI and then reload the page, everything looks reset.

Example: Set "General / Delete all snapshots after" to "5", press "Save" and then press "F5". The field is empty again.

Does SQ store its settings in the database or on the filesystem? May I have wrong access rights then?

We're using an external PostgreSQL database.

Comment: yes SQ store on database. So I think you use the 'in memory' default database ? Are project analyses well saved ?

Comment: No, I'm using external PostgreSQL database. Yes, project analysis is stored.

Comment: and what about the logs ?

Answer (score 1):

If you define a setting in `sonar.properties`, its value will not be rendered in the settings web page - and you are not able to change it there.

Have a look at `Administration / System / System info` to see the properties currently in effect.

To change the value of `Delete all snapshots after`:

- Either change `sonar.dbcleaner.weeksBeforeDeletingAllSnapshots` in your `sonar.properties`
- Or remove `sonar.dbcleaner.weeksBeforeDeletingAllSnapshots` from your `sonar.properties` and set the value in the web user interface (its value will be stored in the database, in this case)

Comment: I did not define any of these properties in sonar.properties.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input. The problem was caused by some totally different reason:

We had the ReSharper plugin installed, which caused a warning in its settings tab like "path to inspectcode and resharper cannot be used simultaneously".

After uninstallation of ReSharper all was fine again and the UI was behaving as expected and displaying all settings' values.